# How to solve ProgrammingError "relation "django_session" does not exist" when using Django with Heroku

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I have looked at different threads on here and can't seem to find the solution. It's presenting itself like its an error in the heroku code (I know its not, I've done something wrong), regardless I am very stuck. I have deployed the django project with sqlite3, no issues and am currently trying to convert it postgreSQL.
My Settings File:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url
from decouple import config
import dj_database_url
import dotenv

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# .env configuration:
dotenv_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env")
if os.path.isfile(dotenv_file):
    dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv_file)

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
#SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-#r@o%yo-#92(0*j%9vn*9l7itkd50l7wadkc=55p$wd46ljl5-'
with open('secret_key.txt', 'r') as f:
    SECRET_KEY = f.readline().strip()

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'core.apps.CoreConfig',
    'files.apps.FilesConfig',

    'django_unused_media', 
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ridgefield.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'global_templates',
            BASE_DIR/'files'/'templates',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ridgefield.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {}
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Australia/Perth'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

#SMTP config

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

django_heroku.settings(locals())

# workaround for an SSL issue
options = DATABASES['default'].get('OPTIONS', {})
options.pop('sslmode', None)
```

I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://bennettgarner.medium.com/deploying-django-to-heroku-connecting-heroku-postgres-fcc960d290d1

But when I try and deploy the Project I get:
[image]

Any Help would be much appreciated and if you need or want to look/check other parts of the code lmk.

Thank you

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py migrate` in your heroku shell?

Comment: I would recommend to immediately delete this post, because your app password for your mail is compromised.

Comment: @IainShelvington I tried to but get this error..
"django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type integer to bytea
LINE 1: ...le" ALTER COLUMN "deleted" TYPE bytea USING "deleted"::bytea"

Comment: @demstar16, please [edit] your question and include the _entire_ error traceback. You'll probably also have to share the migration file that's failing to apply so we can see what you are trying to do.